# Is there a way to find out if iPhone obtained CLLocation by A-GPS, cell tower signal strength or wifi?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, gps

I'm trying to find a property that indicates how iPhone physically obtains `CLLocation`?

As far as I am aware iPhone gets `CLLocation` via either:

1) GPS
2) Cell tower triangulation
3) Wifi ID and signal strength

Can I programmatically refer to something in the publicly accessible libraries to get this?

If there isn't a way to identify it programmatically in the publicly accessible libraries, is there a "round about" way to get the same information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, there is no published way to get this information.

You can use horizontalAccuracy and verticalAccuracy to guess the source, at least between GPS and the others.  You would want to test it to come up with numbers you like, but GPS will usually be better than 10 meters and the others worse.

You can try to manually look up the wifi location and see if it matches the results you get.  You can also use Reachability to see if there is a wifi connection and rule it out if not.

Comment: Hi drawnonward.

Thank you very much for your answer, especially for the additional reference to "Reachability".

Much appreciated,

Roger

Answer (score 1):

There aren't any public ways of accessing this information.

Comment: Hi Snow Crash,

I can't find any public ways of getting the info either, and the others agree with you. Thank you for your help and response to my question.

Much appreciated,

Roger

Answer (score 0):

Look into [Location Based Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location-based_service), not sure if you can do this yet for the iPhone in the SDK so you might Google for it as well.

Comment: Hi Phill,

Thank you for your direction re: Location Based Services. I will definitely look at the link you provided.

Much appreciated,

Roger

Answer (score 0):

Try this magic:

```
@interface CLLocation(){
    @property(readonly, nonatomic) int type;
}
```