# Is there a way to detect the source of coordinates

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, cllocation

In order to improve my geolocation i would like to check if the coordinates received in the delegate method locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation: came from a gps signal or a wifi signal. Is it possible ?

I know the is a way to detect if the coordinates came from a gps signal if the coordinates attribute "verticalAccuracy" is superior to 0 but it seems to be the case even for indoor geolocation (so a geolocation based on wifi)

Comment: Looks like there is no public way of doing it. See [this][1] answer.



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095720/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-if-iphone-obtained-cllocation-by-a-gps-cell-tower-si

Comment: Thanks tronbabylove, i didn't find this SO question. So it seems to be impossible to get these informations...